# Formation of the free group on $S$ is a functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, free-groups, functors

Example 1.2.4 in [Leinster](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) says that an assignment of the free group $\mathcal F(S)$ on $S$ to every set $S$ is a functor. He gives an example of how to assign to a particular function of sets $f:S\to S'$ a homomrphism $F(f):F(S)\to F(S')$ but doesn't give a general proof. So I was wondering how to prove that it is indeed a functor?

(He doesn't give a rigorous definition of the free group on $S$ either, but let's assume that a formal definition is known (it's the set of equivalence classes of reduced words on the set $S\cup S^{-1}$, where $S^{-1}$ is the set consisting of all symbols $s^{-1}$ for all $s\in S$, with the operation of concatenation).)

Comment: What have you attempted for this problem? What do you additionally need to verify to show that $F$ is a functor - and how do you think you could do this?

Comment: Hint: A group homomorphism is entirely defined by the image of its generators.

Comment: The way a category theorist would define a free group would probably be different from the definition you give. They would say a free group is defined by a universal property, in which case it is pretty transparent how to do this. It isn't super hard to do it with reduced words but you basically need to show the equivalence between the definitions which can take a bit of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, just in case you don't know, given a set $S$, the free group $F(S)$ satisfies the following universal property mentioned by @PaulPlummer in the comments. Given a group $G$ and a morphism of sets (i.e. a function) $f\colon S \to G$, there exists a group homomorphism $\phi_f\colon F(S) \to G$ that *extends* the map $f$. I mean this in the sense that if $i\colon S \to F(S)$ is inclusion, then $\phi_f\circ i = f$ as a set map $S \to G$. Moreover the map $\phi_f$ is unique. I'd draw you a pretty diagram, but it wants a diagonal arrow.

If this is new to you, try proving it!

---

Now, given a function $f\colon S \to S'$, we want to show that there exists a group homomorphism $F(f) \colon F(S) \to F(S')$ and that the assignment $f \mapsto F(f)$ is functorial. To use the above property, we need a set map $S \to F(S')$. Let $i_{S'} \colon S' \to F(S')$ be the inclusion. We'll use $i_{S'}\circ f$; I claim that the resulting group homomorphism $F(f) := \phi_{i_{S'}\circ f}$ works. Its existence is afforded to us by the universal property.

To show functoriality, we need to show that the identity function $\operatorname{id}_S\colon S \to S$, is sent to the identity homomorphism $F(\operatorname{id_S}) = \operatorname{id}_{F(S)}$, and that composition is respected, i.e. $F(g\circ f) = F(g)\circ F(f)$.

Both properties are straightforward exercises and left to you. Note the usefulness of the uniqueness statement above!

Comment: But $i$ is not quite inclusion, right? It assigns to a letter $a$ the equivalence class $[a]$ of the word $a$. (I guess in this case this class (set) consists of the single element which is the word $a$.)

Comment: it *is* inclusion between the set $S$ and the underlying set of the *group* $F(S)$. You are correct that it is *not* an inclusion between the set $S$ and the set of words in the alphabet $S \cup S^{-1}$. I guess if you would like, it is just an injection; I'm happy to think of the set $S$ as living inside the group.

Comment: You said to note the usefulness of the uniqueness statement. I sketched the proof of functoriality, but I'm not sure how uniqueness is used. It can be used to conclude that the functor is faithfull, as far as I understand. By the way, is it full?

Comment: I think I used the uniqueness statement in my (mental) proof that $F(g\circ f) = F(g)\circ F(f)$.

Comment: @user634426 I think that it is not full. For instance, the homomorphism $f\colon\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ given by $n \mapsto 2n$ is not $F(g)$ for some function from a one-element set to itself. ($\mathbb{Z}$ is the free group on a one-element set)